# How to do a simple mysqli query for a similar value?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am looking for just a basic query using mysqli to search table for a particular value.  For example; If 'a' exist in a table then echo 'already exists'. 
Please help as I am still learning to move away from deprecated code.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'agents');
$result = $mysqli->query('select * from project');
if ($result) 
{
    $check = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
       $check[] = $row['projectname'];
    }
}
$a = 'a';
if ($a = $check) 
{
    echo "<script type='text/jscript'>
        alert('already exists.')
        </script>";
}
```

Comment: why don't you use where clause??

Comment: use if(in_array($a,$check['column name']))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases are designed to do searching for you with `WHERE` clauses. There's no need to read the entire table when you can let the database do it for you.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS found FROM project WHERE projectname = '$a'");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
if ($row['found'] > 0) {
    echo "<script type='text/jscript'>alert('already exists.')</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'agents');
$result = $mysqli->query("select * from project where projectName = 'a'");
if($result->num_rows > 0)
echo "already exists";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic error in your code. You try to compare array ($check) with string ($a). Try something like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'agents');

$result = $mysqli->query('select * from project');
if ($result) {
    $check = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $projectname = $row['projectname'];
        if($projectname == 'a')
        {
            echo "<script type='text/jscript'>alert('already exists.')</script>";
            break;
        }
        $check[] = $row['projectname'];
    } 
    print_r($check);
}
else
{
    echo "<script type='text/jscript'>alert('mysqli error')</script>";
}
```

This code will check every projectname in your table and will show alert if it exists projectname = 'a'.

P.s. If you want to contact with your database in really good way read about PDO driver (http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)